# redirect to the django project

Tags: python, django

good afternoon, there was a problem when creating the project. the situation is as follows, the built-in view logout does not work correctly. when I log out of the project on the site page on behalf of the user, I will be redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/logout /. moreover, everything is working properly in another project. below are the variables from the settings file, urls and the button template:

urls.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
    from django.urls import path

    from users.apps import UsersConfig
    from users.views import RegisterView, ProfileView

    app_name = UsersConfig.name


    urlpatterns = [
        path('', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
        path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='users:login'), name='logout'),
        path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
        path('profile/', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    ]
```

settings.py

```
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
    LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

template

```
    <div class="col-sm-4 offset-md-1 py-4">
        <h4 class="text-white">Меню</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="{% url 'catalog:home' %}" class="text-white">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'catalog:contact' %}" class="text-white">Контакты</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'blog:blog' %}" class="text-white">Блог</a></li>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'users:logout' %}" class="text-white">Выйти</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'users:profile' %}" class="text-white">Профиль</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'users:login' %}" class="text-white">Войти</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'users:register' %}" class="text-white">Регистрация</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

redirect to the main page

Comment: Since Django-5.0, you need to make a POST request to logout.

Comment: you can read more about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'profile'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
```